# Use Regex in this Linq query?

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I am using this Linq to find the highest int in a list, so that I can increment it and add it to the end of the next string:

```
var CableNumber = CList.Select(v => int.Parse(v.CableNumber.Substring(n))).Max();
```

However, because the strings aren't a fixed length, I was thinking of inserting a `Regex.Match` in there, possibly something like:

```
n = Regex.Match(CableNumber, @"\d{3}", RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
```

To specify; the only format the input strings follow is that it will always have a 3 digit number on the end, possibly followed by a single letter. Some examples:

```
CP1-P-CP2-001 (001)
MOT1PSP2023A (023)
TKSP3-C-FLT2-234-A (234)
```

How could I implement this? Is there a better way?

Comment: Which part you have trouble with? Which is not working?

Comment: `Regex` can't be translated into linq expression, what you could do is executing the query first into `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: Regular expressions are a good way for that. But your 3rd example contradicts what you wrote in the sentance above: the 234 is not followed by a single letter.

Comment: @YuliamChandra He didn't mention SQL, so it shouldn't matter that it can't be translated to a query.

Comment: apologize, I misinterpreted the `Linq query` as `Linq to entities`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I'm trying to figure out how to get the position (`Substring(n)`) for a varying string length. I.E. `Substring(10)` would only work for the first string, but not for the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following uses the regex pattern inside the linq query:

```
string[] strings = { "CP1-P-CP2-001 (001)","MOT1PSP2023A (023)", "TKSP3-C-FLT2-234-A (234)",
                     "InvalidString" };

int? maxValue = strings.Max(x => 
{
    var match = Regex.Match(x, @"\d{3}(?=\D*$)");
    return match.Success ? (int?) int.Parse(match.Value) : null;
});
```

The `int?` is so we can bypass any `string.Empty` coming back from an invalid match and only parse valid matches. If none matched, will return null.

Comment: to specify the numbers in brackets at the end `(001), (023)` are only there to show what part of the string I wanted. They're not actually part of the string itself.

Comment: "The best overloaded method match for 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(string, int)' has some invalid arguments"

Comment: `string, int`? could you show me what you pass to the method? You should be passing two strings.

Comment: as well as "cannot convert from 'char' to string'" and "cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'"

Comment: You're probably passing a different list then what i showed. Show me the code you use.

Comment: Whoops, sorry I accidentally placed it in a `foreach` loop

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
var CableNumber = CList.Select(v => 
    int.Parse(v.CableNumber.Substring(v.CableNumber.Length - 3))).Max();
```

Or to be safe (to prevent string that is less than 3 characters).

```
var CableNumber = CList.Select(v => 
    int.Parse(("000" + v.CableNumber).Substring(("000" + v.CableNumber).Length - 3))).Max();
```

## update

Use [**`LastIndexOfAny`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexofany%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var CableNumber = CList.Select(v => 
    int.Parse(v.CableNumber.Substring(v.CableNumber
        .LastIndexOfAny("0123456789".ToCharArray()) - 2, 3))).Max();
```

Comment: I thought about that, but unfortunately that doesn't allow for any extra characters that might follow after the number (`-A`)

Comment: awesome, now I can create a list and get the highest number from that :) Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You can use the next regex to get last 3 digits in each string:

```
(\d{3})\D*$
```